# How to Switch between Branches and Master for a Local Github Project

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I'm a newbie to Github and I'm sure this is a simple question but I cannot work out what to do.

I have cloned the project from github to my local computer. I can see the master, and if I edit the files I can see changes and push them back to Github.

When I try to create a branch and then edit the local files, the changes appear as uncommited files - however when I switch back to the master the local files do not revert to the masters version.

I am using github for windows and only have one local working directory - any help would be great!

Comment: are you saving your changes in other branch with `git commit` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is by design: It covers the very common use case where you start implementing a feature on the master branch, and just when you are about to commit it, you decide that you want it on another branch instead. You switch to the other branch and "carry over" your uncommitted changes to commit them there.

If you *want* to abandon your changes you can call `git reset --hard` once you're back on the master branch.